# ubuntu 14.04.2 with dual monitor - doesn't log in

Tags: 14.04, login, multiple-monitors, monitor

I have [Ubuntu mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) (based on Ubuntu 14.04.2) on my Lenovo laptop. I also have an LG monitor connected to the VGA output. I am experiencing something weird with this set-up.

The problem is that when I turn on my laptop with the monitor connected, the screen freezes blank right before the login screen and it will remain that way until I disconnect the monitor (there fore I can't login). If I disconnect the monitor, the blank screen unfreezes, the login screen appears and I am able to login successfully. I can then re-connect my monitor, the OS recognizes it, and everything works perfectly from then on.

I have searched the web and found nothing similar. I haven't searched the docs because I don't have any idea of what docs to look. Anyway, I'm really lost here.

By the way, this set-up worked perfectly until two weeks ago, when I had (pure) Ubuntu 14.04 installed. It all started when I installed Mate.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same problem. I am using a TUXEDO 14" Laptop.
For me works a right-mouse-click into the blank (white) screen for unfreezing.

But then there was no usage of keyboard to type the password. I used the on-screen-keyboard from within the disabled menu to login.

Comment: Were you using Mate as well?

Comment: That actually worked. Can't believe it was that simple. Even the keyboard worked after the right-click.