# Can't resume from suspend with dual monitors on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, suspend

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 with NVidia GeForce 1080 and dual monitor setup. After entering "suspend" I can't resume OS. The screens are black (no signal) and the system is not running (it is not possible to turn it off with a power off button). What's important, everything is fine if I am using only a single display.

What did not help thus far:

1. Switching to different interface (DP -> DVI)
2. Entering suspend from text terminal (ctrl+alt+F1)
3. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771218/cannot-login-after-suspend-with-multiple-monitors)

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the Nvidia driver are you using?

Comment: It's 370. I tried also the latest, to the same effect.

Comment: Can you SSH into machine? You say 'not running' but I am not convinced. Also, does Alt-Ctl-F1 get you a VT? If yes, it is running. I have black screen after ubuntu 17.04. Sometimes system is running, just no video. Other times, I get nothing. I suspect hard disk getting wonky from lots of hard resets...

Comment: Not running as in "hanging without video or any sort of ability to interact with it". No SSH, no VT, no reaction to 'power off' button.

Comment: Have you tried hibernating and had the same issue, could be hardware related, this would help troubleshoot the issue, some cards don't like suspend, if you are able to reboot gracefully see if there are any hints in your previous dmesg logs, do they have any errors standing out?

Comment: Yep, I did - good question. Hibernation works without any problems. There's nothing that raise my eyebrows in the logs. With single display it works fine, regardless which one (24" and 27").

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'm posting here. Have you tried logging out? **CTRL + ALT + T** and enter 'gnome-session-quit'. (blindly of course) and see if that resumes the display?

Also, you mention that you have one 24" and one 27" - That might be the issue on why your Nvidia drivers can't resync.

Try using the article you've linked to see if you can set it to resume with your main monitor only targeting display settings.

Comment: Thanks, but as I explained, the OS is completely unresponsive - see also my comments. What do you mean by "targeting main monitor only"? How do I select specific monitor for resuming from suspend?